# Why do I get FileNotFoundException?

Tags: android, file

to me this seems fine,

still I get a `FileNotFoundException` when I try to access it?

Please what am I doing wrong?

```
   File cacheDir;
   if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
   android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
   {
   //if SDCARD is mounted (SDCARD is present on device and mounted)
   cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
   }
   else
   {
   // if checking on simulator the create cache dir in your application context
   cacheDir=MainActivity.this.getCacheDir();
   }
   if(!cacheDir.exists()){ // create cache dir in your application context
   cacheDir.mkdirs();
   }

   String filename=String.valueOf(rss.getChannel().getItems().get(i).getEnclosure().getUrl().hashCode());

   File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
```

Comment: you should verify that the result of `cacheDir.mkdirs();` is `true`. Possibly you lack permissions to create this directory on the external storage.

Comment: "when I try to access it" -- what is "it"? What specific line in this code are you crashing on?

Comment: @njzk2 me stupid!!! That was it!!! Please njzk2 if you post a answer I will be happy to accept it. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
// ...
cacheDir.mkdirs();
```

According to the documentation for `getExternalStorageDirectory`

> Writing to this path requires the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission

Also, I would recommend to always check the return value of `mkdirs`, which indicates if the directory creation was successful, as the doc for this method says

> Note that this method does not throw `IOException` on failure.